# How to retrieve an object from ResultSet in java?

Tags: java, database, object, constructor, resultset

So I tried to make a getRecord class to retrieves info from database based on the ID the user entered,

```
public Student getRecord(String id) {
        String queryStr = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE ID = ?";
        Student student = null;
        try {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
            stmt.setString(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            int count = 1;
            
            if (rs.next()) {
                String level = rs.getString("Level");
                char level1 = level.charAt(0);
                student = new Student(id, rs.getString("IC"), rs.getString("Name"), level1, rs.getObject("ProgrammeCode"), Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Yr")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return student;
    }
```

So it run the query and call the constructor of student,

```
public Student(String id, String ic, String name, char level, Programme programme, int year) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ic = ic;
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.programme = programme;
        this.year = year;
    }
```

To create an object for student class and then return it to the main program. However, the student constructor also need another object of programme. How can i retrieve the object from the database through ResultSet? I have stucked on this for hours and attempted to use getObject but it didn't work. Please guide me. TQ and have a good day.

Comment: have you even looked at the documentation for the class? It's quite instructive...

Comment: What is the data type of column `ProgrammeCode` in the database table?

Comment: @Abra it should be a string but in the constructor the whole object is required

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks but may you provide a clearer explaination as I'm still quite confused...

Comment: Let me rephrase. Is the data type of column `ProgrammeCode` VARCHAR or CHAR or NCHAR?

Comment: @Abra it is VARCHAR

Comment: `getObject` is a catch-all delivering the base class Object. In your case you evidently could have used `getString`. So the ProgramCode evidently is a text.

Comment: @JoopEggen I attempted that but it gave me error about String cannot be converted to an object of Programme as it is required in the constructor of Student...

Comment: I assume that Java class `Programme` is one that you wrote. Did you write code that converts a `String` object into a `Programme` object? The JDBC driver that you are using does not know how to do that so calling `rs.getObject()` will return a `String`. The JDBC driver maps VARCHAR to `String`. You need to write code that converts that `String` into a `Programme` object.

Comment: There is no `public Programme(String code)`? (`new Programme(rs.getString("ProgrammeCode"))`)?

Comment: @JoopEggen Huge thanks my bro! I copied your code and pasted in it and it worked like a charm! Would you mind to leave a comment with explaination below so in future someone who faced the same problem could save a lot of time :DD Have a nice day ahead!

Comment: In the database one probably stored the program code as (source) text in a TEXT or VARCHAR field: `rs.getString`. You need to construct a Programme from this String: `new Programme(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION FOUND THANKS TO @Joop Eggen**

I managed to solve this by declaring and initializing a new object, replacing the rs.getString("ProgrammeCode"); to  (new Programme(rs.getString("ProgrammeCode"))).